# Describe device regression testing

Tags: testing

How could you describe device regression testing and how it will be carried out, I know what is regression testing but this term is very new for me. I understood this is practised in some companies.

Comment: I could be wrong but this seems like a very broad question. Have you already looked other various articles and resources online?

Comment: I have looked at all the other types of regression testing, but i couldn't find any resource this type of regression testing

Answer (score 2):

I have carried out device regression testing. What I used to do is that,
I used to check the code compatibility across various devices.
Where devices were such that they had internal memory variation, wireless connectivity variations, and all such device factors.

Answer (score 0):

Regression testing is defined as a type of software testing to confirm that a recent program or code change has not adversely affected existing features.

Regression testing is nothing but full or partial selection of already executed test cases which are re-executed to ensure existing functionalities work fine.

Answer (score 0):

device regression testing? I think, We may fix some device specific issue that fix introducing regression or bug in other device it may be device regression testing.

Ex: Some fixing UI breaking issue for samsung,introducing new issues in sony/other devices.